# In a project that depends on a library, how can I override a class definition from that library?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two app projects, A and B, based on a library project C.

All the java code is contained by library project C. Projects A and B only differ in their AndroidManifests, varying their functionality through setting different flag variables.

To give a simplified example, A gives access to a class `ImportExport`, and its method `ImportExport.import()`. The other, app B, doesn't give access to such functionaliy.

I would like to make the `ImportExport.import()` code nonexistent in the compiled app B. Is there a way I could add an empty `ImportExport.import()` method definition to app B, that would override the library's definition of `ImportExport.import()`?

If necessary, I'm also happy with overriding the whole class `ImportExport`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not just using ProGuard for this? Set up your ProGuard rules to keep whatever ImportExport.import() is for A and set up your ProGuard rules to get rid of it for B.

Comment: That would totally work, yes, or using Gradle, or any other build tool. So I understand "using ProGuard" would be the first part of the answer. Now I just need to find out how to do it. I'm using Android Studio, by the way.

Comment: Also, you can use two 2 product flavors instead of 2 different app projects.

Comment: Gabriele, I took a quick look at Gradle multi-flavours, and that looks like a good solution for me. I have only switched to Android Studio recently, and hence temporarily sticking to my pre-Gradle library-based structure. But I will look into switching to multi-flavour build in the near future.